# How do I change the colour of the editors horizontal code highlighter bar?

Tags: scrollbar

how do I change the colour of the horizontal code highlighter bar?

My theme has a green bar that is blocking out the green text when I type and it is very annoying. PLease see the example below.

[image: Example of issue]

I would like the theme but I would just like to change this element to something else like blue.

Do you know of a way that I can change it?

Thanks

Comment: Please do not post images, post code as code and the actual text of any error messages.

Comment: Please indicate what program you are using.

Comment: Hi I am using Visual Studio Code. That's the forum that I thought I posted in.

Comment: @dmcgrandle The problem is not code related and posting a code example would not be of any benefit. Please read the post properly and you might understand.